# adb connection by wifi getting killed when a new USB attached/detached

Tags: android, usb, adb

I develop on my tablet using `android studio`. 
The tablet is connected to the computer by wifi using

`adb connect <ip_andress>:5555`

My application contains listeners for USB devices `attached/detached`. 
But unfourtunately, when I connect/disconnect usb device to/from the tablet, the adb connection is getting `killed`, and I can no longer see the device under "adb devices".

Comment: Did you manage to solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a *adb-connection-by-wifi* what gets killed. It is just that USB enumerations affect the `sys.usb.*` system properties which on many devices is causing restart of `adbd` regardless whether it's being used over `USB` or `tcpip`.

Do `grep "stop adbd" /init*rc` to see what I mean.

You could either comment out those `stop adbd` lines or just disconnect the USB cable *before* running your `adb connect` command.

Comment: Editing init*rc files is not possible for me, as my device isn't rooted. Also, running "adb connect" after disconnecting the USB caused "unable to connect. Connection refused".

Answer (score 0):

I was never able to connect my cellphone with my computar through wi-fi.

I had already given up. I followed all the instructions and tips, and nothing worked.

Finally, I did what no one said to do.

I've connected the phone to the WiFi network provided by the cable modem itself and not to some (not all) additional networks that are included in the router.

At home I use one of these networks, because I use a `Deco Tp-Link router`, which propagates the signal to my entire house, but this network is NOT compatible with  *ADB*. It does not identify it as belonging to the same network.

After this, I use the normal procedure described [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb).

**a)** Connect cellphone with a *USB* cable

**b)** Find the `IP_Phone` depends on system in the cell phone. Here I use `Settings`, `About Phone`, `Status` and `IP address`.

**c)** Run the following adb commands  in `Command Prompt` (Windows) or `Terminal` (Linux), where `IP_Phone` is the IP above mentioned.   Normally `adb.exe` is an executable stored in computer path. `adb` is already [included](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb?hl=pt-br) in *Android Studio* package.

```
adb tcpip 5555
adb connect IP_Phone
```

**d)** Now disconnect *USB* cable and it's ready. The cellphone model continues to appear in the status line in the top of *Android Studio*.

-/-

The best wifi is that defined in Cable Modem. It, unlike an any account defined in  my router, answers to a ping command.

```
ping IP_Phone
```

Comment: I know, but the official instruction of Android Studio documantation is turn off USB `after adb connect`  command

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect the usb cable just before running `adb connect <*ip_address_of_your_phone*>`