# Trigger a USB connection event without severing adb server

Tags: android, shell, automation, adb, appium

I need to be able to connect two android devices wirelessly to my computer, connect those devices to each other via OTG cable, and be able to trigger the same usb connection event on one of the devices at anytime using adb. The first way I thought of doing this was to manually switch from mtp, to ptp on one of the devices (adb shell setprop...), ultimately creating the usb connection event on the other device, however doing so severs the wireless connection between my computer and the device I switched usb config on.

Any suggestions on how to do simulate/trigger the usb connection event on one of the devices without actually re-plugging in the OTG cable or severing the wireless connection?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40118234/1778421

Comment: @AlexP. How would I go about commenting out the 'stop adbd' lines?