# ADB over network just work if device is connected

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

**UPDATED**

This question is not a duplicate from [adb connection by wifi getting killed when a new USB attached/detached](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40105706/6733404) (it don't resolve my issue and here, the problem occour when a **new** usb is attach or detach), my problem is different

I'am runnig this command to connect my Nexus 4 to work over network

> C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools>adb tcpip 5555
>
> C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools>adb connect 192.168.1.120:5555
>
> connected to 192.168.1.120:5555

This above command work fine and my device is enable to `Deployment Target` as follow

[image]

The option work fine until I do disconnect my device via usb from computer, so **the ADB over network disappear as follow**

[image]

How to solve it?

Thanks a lot for any sugestion

Answer (score 0):

This works over WiFi, after running

```
adb tcpip 5555
```

disconnect the cable then run

```
adb connect 192.168.1.120:5555
```

Comment: Not work for me