# Unpluging usb cable also disconnects wireless adb connection

Tags: android, adb

Here is what I'm doing:

1.Plugging phone through usb

2.turning on usb debugging (MTP configuration)

3.revoke USB debugging auth

4.`adb kill-server`

5.`adb tcpip 5555`

6.unplugging usb cable (or I do this in last step, doesn't matter)

7.`adb connect 192.168.1.100`

resault:

> unable to connect to 192.168.1.100:5555: cannot connect to
>   192.168.1.100:5555: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)

Or if I unplug the cable in last step it will connect

> connected 192.168.1.100:5555

but after unplugging the cable `adb devices` list is empty.

I saw many question regarding this problem but nothing worked for me.

P.S  My device is not rooted (Honor 8 lite, API 24)

Comment: @crammeur In the link the first method root is required and the second method is exactly things that I've done

Comment: Do you use `adb start-server` after the `adb kill-server`

Comment: Are your PC and  mobile in same network(means both are connected to same wifi)??

Comment: @Chandrakanth yes,  I think I found the cause which is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40118234/6605907 , but still the solution did not worked for me.